# postgresql current_setting('request.jwt.claim.id'::text, true)::integer;

Tags: postgresql, function, jwt, claims-based-identity

I am trying to create one function to get id from JWT token and pass it to another function. When I test from postman by passing JWT token I am getting response as `null`, if my payload consists of only id then the response is coming.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_entities_test1()
    RETURNS TABLE(education_group integer) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
declare 
myid integer;
BEGIN

myid = (current_setting('request.jwt.claim.id'::text, true))::integer; 

RETURN QUERY
 SELECT education_group_id from rbac_get_entities( myid );
 END
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
current_setting('request.jwt.claims', true)::json->>'sub'
```